# Jasmine failure: Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for postSkillforMember()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a method which does not return nothing. The method calls a service to perform a Http POST. I have mocked my service and set it as a parameter within SpyOn. The second parameter in the SpyOn call is the name of the method that contains the post operation. In this case, the method name is postSkillforMember. When I run ng test, Jasmine spec list failures throws the following error:

Jasmine Spec List | Failures:

```
AddSkillModalComponent > Testing addSkill() success
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for postSkillforMember()
```

What I am doing wrong? This is the method in my component.ts that I want to test:

Method to test:

```
addSkill(): void {
this.successCallback=(skill: any) => {
  this.showAlert = false;
  this.activeModal.close(skill);
};
this.errorCallback=(error: any)=>{
  this.showAlert=true;
};
const skillFormBody = {
  skill: {
      "id": this.itemFormGroup.get("skill")?.value.id,
      "skill": ""
  },
  skillLevel: {
      "id": this.itemFormGroup.get("skillLevel")?.value.id,
      "skillLevel": ""
  }
}

this._skillAddService.postSkillforMember(
  this.memberId,
  skillFormBody,
  this.successCallback,
  this.errorCallback
);}
```

My spec ts mocks the service within describe:

describe in add-skill-modal.component.ts:

```
  describe('AddSkillModalComponent', () => {
  let component: AddSkillModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddSkillModalComponent>;
  let mockSkillAddService: jasmine.SpyObj<SkillAddService>;}
```

And, finally, this is the unit test I wrote for my method:

it in add-skill-modal.component.ts:

```
    it('Testing addSkill() success', () => {
    spyOn(mockSkillAddService, 'postSkillforMember');
    component.addSkill();
    expect(component.showAlert).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your `TestBed.configureTestingModule({`?

Make sure you create a spyObj for `SkillAddService` and add it to the providers.

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  // make sure you create this spy object with postSkillforMember public method to be mocked
  mockSkillAddService = jasmine.createSpyObj<SkillAddService>('SkillAddService', ['postSkillforMember']);
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [...],
    // provide the mock instead of the real one
    providers: [{ provide: SkillAddService, useValue: mockSkillAddService }],
  }).compileComponents();
}));

 it('Testing addSkill() success', () => {
    // no need to spy anymore
    // spyOn(mockSkillAddService, 'postSkillforMember');
    component.addSkill();
    expect(component.showAlert).toBeFalsy();
    // can do:
    expect(mockSkillAddService.postSkillforMember).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```